# How do you bring a question to the attention of members of another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion

I am of the opinion that the question [What math courses should be taught to undergrad electrical engineers: a 40 years update](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/6124/what-math-courses-should-be-taught-to-undergrad-electrical-engineers-a-40-years) would benefit from attention from members of [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

How can that be achieved without cross-posting or migrating the question, or is such a practice not encouraged by Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in way to share question over several sites, but the idea comes up with some frequency, see for example a feature-request to support [asking on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131950/asking-on-multiple-sites-soft-migration).

While for general cross-site promotion there is the hot network question list (in the sidebar)  and also the general http://stackexchange.com/   neither is designed to get attention for a particular question.

A workaround I am aware of is on the [meta-site of MathOverflow where there is a question to collect questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1967/) on [math.SE] that users want to promote, this is however a bit of a special case.

Now, for your actual question: To get attention for a specific question from a specific site, I would  **join the chat of that site** and mention the question there. Chat is quite informal, so this should be alright. If there is a lot going on in the room it  might be good form to ask if it is alright before posting, if it is rather idle I would just post it in a polite way.

To post on the meta-site of that site is also a possibility; but this could be seen as slightly intrusive (especially if one  should be a complete outsider to that site), yet it might still be an option. In any case, I would recommend to try chat first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried chat and received a friendly response. That said, I'm not sure how visible that makes the question. However, I hesitate to act in a more intrusive manner. Perhaps the OP would like to cross-post at some stage, assuming the question receives insufficient attention here.